# Exporting javascript generated csv in Firefox only exports first line, works fine in chrome

Tags: javascript, csv, firefox

This worked well about 2 months ago and all of a sudden Firefox doesn't like anything except the first line. While debugging the code however the `data` variable contains the full CSV document. But once the file is downloaded I only get the very first line. This works in Chrome which I do find a bit odd as it used to work in both.

Any suggestions of how to fix this?

Below is my export script.

```
PerformanceTableController.prototype.exportSplitTimes = function () {
    var resultListId,
        resultList,
        columnId,
        csv = [],
        csvContent,
        row,
        i, l,
        filename,
        data,
        link;

    for (resultListId in this.raceData.resultLists) {
        if (this.raceData.resultLists.hasOwnProperty(resultListId)) {
            resultList = this.raceData.resultLists[resultListId];

            csv.push(this.getCSVClassTitle(resultList));
            csv.push(this.getCSVColumnHeaders());

            for (i = 0, l = resultList.performanceList().length; i < l; i += 1) {
                row = [];

                for (columnId in resultList.performanceList()[i]) {
                    if (resultList.performanceList()[i].hasOwnProperty(columnId)) {
                        if (resultList.performanceList()[i][columnId].value !== undefined) {
                            row.push(resultList.performanceList()[i][columnId].value);
                        }
                    }
                }

                csv.push(row.join(","));
            }
            console.log(csv);
        }
    }

    if (csv.length === 0) {
        return;
    }

    filename = this.raceData.race.event.name + ' - ' + this.raceData.race.name + '.csv';

    csvContent = csv.join("\n");
    if (!csvContent.match(/^data:text\/csv/i)) {
        csvContent = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + '\uFEFF' + csvContent;
    }
    data = encodeURI(csvContent);

    link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('href', csvContent);
    link.setAttribute('download', filename);
    link.style.display = 'none';
    // Without this line, Firefox is not able to open the CSV
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
};
```

Comment: can you try to `encodeURIComponent(csvContent)` ?

Comment: Tried it, same problem! :(

Comment: ah sorry I missed you already `encodeURI` it. Actually, you should not encodeURI the header part, `csvContent = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' +  encodeURIComponent(csvContent);`

Comment: Thats some sweet magic right there. Want to make it as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firefox is more picky about characters that are set in URIs than chrome. Some characters (such as `#`) are reserved, if your data contains one of it, your file download will fail.

You already call `encodeURI`, but you do it on the full URI, while you should keep the header non-encoded.

So changing `csvContent = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + '\uFEFF' + csvContent;`
to `csvContent = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csvContent);` and removing the `encodeURI(csvContent)` that comes later should fix your issue.